# binary file decrypt

Tags: files, conversion, file-format

I want to see the message inside this binary file:

```
]�$�r�ux����f��aY64QH���K�z{������y�ߗ��y�m����Ǖ�} ��cy@^��+|�%E(H��*�I�P�����7��8�=$�.�`ïc�
                                                                                                     !w|����7L�
                                                                                                               I4�Rԗ%�7F���$����a�Z�(�Y��1  ��4Y���C'�z��������^�\�-��-�hU��ʺ^KC�7������.DΖB/�����dB�3_��Ac�LȊ��R���[���l�(p���<g9�$����M�]�9�
                                      ��Q����Ƶ�i���N֕[c`�$;��hy8�S�
�bJ���T�����w_6�C;�Z�                                           �4��ˋ�Řog�$�:�F���l�+��6�o-� ����Q�=��#�O|a\
                        �z�����J;)<�vd��o� ��U�ә��|�Sţ6�����m=�:i�Y�����G�fJEt�*x����khC�>�
                                                                                                 |0��*At}�ao�mj[L��d�vϻ�
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I tried with `xxd myfile` but I didn't see the message.

Comment: Can you add the output of `file filename`?

Comment: @Haxiel myfile: LZMA compressed data, non-streamed, size 548

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include that information. That is essential.

Comment: What even makes you think that it's encrypted? And if it's encrypted, how do you hope people to decrypt it? And how do you hope people to help you when you post binary content into a text field, which removes most of the information? If you want help to figure out what this file is, tell us in what context you got it and post actual content, not butchered content.

Answer (score 3):

If your file is compressed using `lzma` (often `xz --format=lzma`), you can use that tool to decompress it. For example:

```
$ echo "hello world" > file
$ lzma file
$ cat file.lzma 
]���������4I���:3_��    �/���t
```

Now, read it it:

```
$ lzcat file.lzma 
hello world
```

Or decompress it:

```
$ unlzma file.lzma
$ cat file 
hello world
```

Or:

```
xz --format=lzma --decompress file.lzma
```

Comment: when  i try this: xz --format=lzma --decompress file.lzma ==format  he gave me this xz: myfile: Filename has an unknown suffix, skipping

Comment: @gogumartalogu22 does `lzcat myfile` work? If it does, then just run `mv myfile myfile.lzma` and then you can run `xz --format=lzma --decompress myfile.lzma`

Comment: it doesn`t work, can u show the message from my binary file please

Comment: @gogumartalogu22 no, you need to run it. I can't copy the data, that doesn't work. Please edit your question and show us the commands you tried and their output.